# How to view console output for an eclipse plugin installed in the workbench in which it was created?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Hi iam new to eclipse plugin development , iam trying to create a simple plugin having a menu . I have installed it in the same eclipse workbench in which it was developed . However if i click on it i dont see the output in the console view . Howveevr if i run the project as a seperate eclipse app in a seperate workbench it works but shows the output in original workbench in which it was developed .

Can anybody help me out how to view the plugin output in the same workbench , irrespective of whether it is a new workbench or the same workbench in which it was developed

Any help is highly appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is to start the workbench as `eclipsec`. This eclipse launcher opens a terminal window *next* to the workbench in which console output (i.e. things written to System.err / System.out) appears.

Comment: Thank you Rudiger this is what i wanted but iam just curious why eclipse developers were not able to incorporate that functionality to the console .

Comment: @learner It is not something that plugins generally need to do. Those plugins that want to use a console use the console APIs, this gives them much more control over the console.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks again iam now clear with the concept , thanks to all for taking out time from your schedule for my query :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to put output in the console in both cases.

When you run in a separate workbench the console is just showing the output from System.out and System.err. Your plugin is running as part of a separate Eclipse in a new JVM, the Eclipse console is showing everything that is output by that JVM.

When you are running in the same workbench you would have to use the console APIs in the `org.eclipse.ui.console` package and extension points such as `org.eclipse.ui.console.consoleFactories` to create a console and write to it.

Comment: Hi Greg , thank you for suggestion but can you please explain  the reason for the first scenario that you have mentioned in your answer